# iTextSharp remove line

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

How can I remove "line" shape from the pdf file using iTextSharp?

I try:

```
var shape = page.GetAsStream(PdfName.LINE); //return null

var resources = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(page.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)) as PdfDictionary; //return dictonary
var resShape = resources.GetAsStream(PdfName.LINE); //return null

PdfReader.KillIndirect(shape);
PdfReader.KillIndirect(resShape);
```

What I do wrong?

Thx!

Comment: What is a "line" shape?

Comment: Sorry for my english. vector figure (picture) which can be drawn in any pdf reader (such as Acrobat Reader)

Comment: Do you draw it as an annotation? Or directly in the page content? Is it actually a line drawing command or is it a slim rectangle filling command?

Comment: In that case you have to inspect the annotations of the page.

Comment: so how I can do that? =\

Comment: I was found solution. Thank', mkl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 PdfDictionary pg = reader.GetPageN(1);
        PdfArray annotsArray = pg.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if (annotsArray != null)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < annotsArray.Size; k++)
            {
                PdfDictionary annot = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annotsArray[k]);
                if(annot.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE).ToString() =="/Line")
                {
                    annotsArray.Remove(k);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have another question. How I can remove figures (rectangle, etc), which drawed like not an anotation?